# Yii: Best Performance Benificial way to include JS/Ajax functions in CGridview

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Yii newbie here 
I have tried more than once to figure out a way to include an Ajax/JS function in an easy clean way in my CGRIDVIEW,
the code is basically

```
'click'=> "function (){
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('news-grid', {
    type:'POST',
    url:$(this).attr('href'),
    success:function(data) {
        $('#AjFlash').html(data).fadeIn().animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 3000).fadeOut('slow');

        $.fn.yiiGridView.update('news-grid');
    }
})
return false;
```

}"

In your opinion, whats the cleanest, most performance benificial way to include this?
Thank you for your time !!!

Comment: what are you trying to do anyways? and why are you calling $.fn.yiiGridView.update('news-grid'); on success again?

Comment: Well basically, I am calling a controller function to update a database value and update the gridview accordingly .  I followed this tutorial, http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/410/create-custom-button-button-with-ajax-function-in-cgridview/

Comment: `$.fn.yii...` is deprecated, new syntax is `$('#news-grid').yiiGridView('update');`

Comment: So in order for me to reload CGridview only (not the whole page), I can directly use this function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but I dont see necesary to force the grid to update twice on a single operation, I also don't like to include my javascript like that. Depending on what I need there are several approaches, for the sake of this answer ill show you the easiest one:

Create a global object, in a separate file:

```
//app.js
var App = {
  updateSomething: function () {
    $.post(
      $(this).attr('href'),
      success:function(data) {
        $('#AjFlash').html(data).fadeIn().animate({
          opacity: 1.0
        }, 3000).fadeOut('slow');
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update('news-grid');
      }
    );
    return false;
  }
};
```

And the you can include that file from your controller by calling [CCLientScript::registerScriptFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScriptFile-detail)

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl."js/app.js");
```

And on your grid:

```
'click'=> "js:App.updateSomething",
```

There are much better approaches, but this is the more simple for js beginners that want to have some kind of organization.

Comment: Thank you Asgaroth for the quick answer! I am still a JS/AJAX beginner, what I am trying to achieve here is updating a value using CButtonColumn, in the url I have added a link to the controller action, but what I want to achieve now is update the cgridview without having to reload the whole page. Unfortunately I followed this tutorial Since it was the only one I found. If you can point me to a better more extensive one, I would be thanking you forever!

Comment: It absolutely did, thank you! but the page is being reloaded, but as I said I was trying to achieve it in a preformance benificial way where only that grid is updated.